# Having Trouble Harness Training my Macaw

Tags: behavior, training, birds

I have been trying to harness train my 1 year old macaw, but it is not working out well. She is comfortable with the harness around her and I have been trying to convince her to overcome her fear of having it over her head and around her neck. I have been awarding her favorite treats, which are sunflower seeds, to her every time she pokes her head through the head loop quickly to gain her trust. I am just stuck on this part of the process of training her. I would really like to have her outside with me so she can experience it for herself. Do any of you have tips and tricks of harness training a bird who is afraid of the head loop? I do not agree with the idea of forcing it on her considering the amount of stress it will cause. Please let me know if you have any information I need. Thank you.